# Semicolon or Comma? SAT

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

I am confused as to whether this sentence should have a comma or semicolon.

> Walker was not only a trailblazer in the medical field (,/;) she was also a relentless visionary who bravely challenged many of the social prejudices of her day.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of this site is that you have attempted some initial research— in short, which do *you* think is correct, and why, and why are you unsure? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: It depends...  When did the person grading the test take freshman English in college?

Comment: commas let the speaker breathe, semicolon's form a list

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Commas have nothing to do with respiration; moreover, semicolons have several uses.

Comment: Typical SAT question -- nothing to do with the supposed test topic; everything to do with second guessing the test maker. Is he trying to trick you into accepting a comma splice?

Comment: @deadrat I agree. Punctuation is about the logical structure of the information communicated by written language. Pauses in spoken language perform the same function and are the way in which the punctuation is interpreted by someone reading aloud, which is why thinking about where you would pause when speaking gives a guide to the placement of punctuation. Unless you are a playwright like Samuel Beckett, of course!

Comment: @BoldBen There is no doubt an overlap between punctuation marks and speech artifacts. And here we're talking about commas and pauses. But pauses in a spoken sentence are an inaccurate guide to placing commas in the written version.

Comment: @deadrat I still think we're in agreement. I was suggesting that pauses _can_ provide a guide (however inaccurate) to the placement of punctuation. This was meant to be in contrast to the 'rule' that many people use which states that commas are placed "to give the reader a chance to take a breath".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a comma there. Two independent clauses that complete a thought is where I'd use a semicolon--if I used a semicolon at all. "Walker was a trailblazer; she bravely challenged the social prejudices of her day." Two complete sentences. One thought. Anyway, that's how I think of it. But I'm no expert; I write novels.

Nowadays it's rare to find a semicolon in a novel, even commas are endangered. Interestingly enough, they read fine with less punctuation--but editors cringe. Oh, another use is after a long series of commas sometimes a semicolon is used to give the reader a breath.

Comment: The first sentence of your second paragraph makes me cringe; I would have used a semicolon there.

Comment: @MT_Head Do you suppose the irony was intended or unintended?

Comment: Readers don't need punctuation marks to tell them when to breathe.

Comment: @deadrat I wondered about that; I wondered, and I still don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If I were an SAT question asker, and I had to explain to my supervisor in the SAT hierarchy why the particular question that you're asking about is SAT-worthy, here's what I'd say:

*This question will trip up people who don't know the difference between a sentence that begins*

> *Walker was not only a trailblazer in the medical field*

*and a sentence that begins*

> *Besides being a trailblazer in the medical field*

*In the second example, you would have to use a comma—not a semicolon—because the "Besides ..." wording is an introductory clause, not an independent clause. But in the first example, the "Walker was not only..." wording is an independent clause. And in SAT Land, two independent clauses cannot be joined merely by a comma; they must be joined by a semicolon or stronger punctuation, or by a comma plus an appropriate conjunction. So it would be correct to say*

> *Not only was Walker a trailblazer in the medical field, but also she was ...*

*and it would be correct to say*

> *Walker was not only a trailblazer in the medical field; she was also ...*

*and it would be correct to say*

> *Walker was not only a trailblazer in the medical field. She was also ...*

*But it would be wrong in SAT Land to say*

> *Walker was not only a trailblazer in the medical field, she was also ...*

*because that punctuation constitutes a dread comma splice (as understood in SAT Land). And I guarantee you, boss, that this question will satisfy the requirement of drawing wrong (in SAT Land) answers on at least 29% of all tests—so I think we've got a winner here!*

Back in the real world, many of these propositions are debatable. But you aren't taking the test in the real world, are you?